# Unzip all files in zip archive with inline command

Tags: python

I have a zip file, but no unzipping tool installed.  I do have python installed, but I can't easily create a python script file on this machine.  How do I unzip the contents of the zip file using the python executable's `-c` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to be this:

`python -c "import zipfile;file=zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip');file.extractall('.')"`

The contents of `archive.zip` will be placed into the directory this command is executed from.